# Creating a Geoserver WFS store using the REST API

Tags: geoserver

I am new to Geoserver and I am trying to create a WFS (Web Feature Server (NG)) store using the REST API however, I am getting the following error 'Unable to determine datastore type from connection parameters'

```json
{
    "dataStore": {
        "name": "testWfsAi",
        "description": "string",
        "enabled": true,
        "type": "Web Feature Server (NG)",
        "workspace": {
            "name": "testWorkspace",
            "link": "string"
        },
        "connectionParameters": {
            "entry": [
                {
                    "key": "GET_CAPABILITIES_URL",
                    "value": "geoserver/DWM/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the following endpoint: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/testWorkspace/datastore

I am getting a 201 response however in the Tomcat logs it shows as follows

[Tomcat log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgVfk.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please [edit] the question to show the URL you are sending the request to and the full response you receive from the server